# PHP display database call before submission

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm troubleshooting someone else's code and I'm not accustomed to calling databases in this way.  It's using Codeigniter and all I want to do it assemble my own version of this SQL call to test in phpMyAdmin.

```
$this->db->select('c1.company_id, c1.name, u.first_name, u.last_name, c2.address1, c2.city, c2.prov_stat, c2.country, c1.url, u.email');
$this->db->from('company AS c1');
$this->db->join('contact AS c2', 'c1.company_id = c2.company_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('users as u', 'c1.user_id = u.id', 'left');
$this->db->where('c2.checked_by_ecole = 0');
$this->db->order_by('c1.name');
```

Is there an existing PHP function I can use to see what the SQL statement looked like in its final format before it was submitted?

Comment: `print_r([get_class_methods($this->db),var_dump($this->db)]);`

Answer (score 0):

Right before you run the query use `get_compile_select()`

```
$this->db->select('c1.company_id, c1.name, u.first_name, u.last_name, c2.address1, c2.city, c2.prov_stat, c2.country, c1.url, u.email');
$this->db->from('company AS c1');
$this->db->join('contact AS c2', 'c1.company_id = c2.company_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('users as u', 'c1.user_id = u.id', 'left');
$this->db->where('c2.checked_by_ecole = 0');
$this->db->order_by('c1.name');

die('<pre>'.$this->db->get_compile_select());
```

You can find the get() and get_compile_select() documentation for ci 3 here;

Comment: I think you mean `get_compiled_select()` as `_compile_select()` is likely a private method.